# How do i sign a java Applet?

Tags: java, html, applet

I made an applet that would draw some triangles, I used the following html code:

```
    <html>
<title>Triangulo retangulo</title>
<hr>
<applet code="clas.class" width="320" height="120">
</applet>
<hr>
</html>
```

It only works when my java security is at medium but warns me there is no signature, I tried making a signature like this:

```
/**
*@Author me
*
**/
```

no success.
I searched google and found this
http://sickpea.com/2009/7/how-to-self-sign-a-java-applet
The site said to sign with this code:

```
$ keytool -genkey -alias sickpea -validity 3650 -dname \"CN=Sickpea, OU=Engineering, O=Sickpea, L=San Francisco, S=CA, C=US"
$ keytool -selfcert -alias sickpea -validity 3650
$ jarsigner mindterm.sickpear.jar sickpea
```

I don't recognize this code, I tried putting it on the java code, then on the html code, still no success...
can somebody help me?
PS: I'm new to programming

Comment: What you found are commands to execute in a shell, not source code statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Java code, those are commands you have to type from a terminal (`cmd` in Windows). Modify the `sickpea` name to match yours (and the details too).

Please be aware that recent JVMs will no more accept self-signed applets because of security reasons.

In fact, the signature certifies that the applet comes from you (as identified by the details of the certificate). As you can imagine, the certification is essentially worth nothing if it comes from yourself, it is like saying "trust me".

If you want to deploy this applet, then get a valid signing certificate from an external autority (CA).

Comment: Darn, where can I get a valid certificate from an external autority?

Comment: I'm trying to make a site with my friend, he knows html, I know java, it would be a shame if my applets don't work :(

Comment: Java Applets are a broken and deprecated technology which dates back to the 1990s. Most browsers even disable Java by default. I suggest using HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript. Of course you will have to learn Javascript (which is not at all related to Java), but it's not difficult if you already know a programming language, plus there are a lot of tutorials on the web.